Android Nsd: onServiceLost() not triggered
I need to connect from the Android app to a bunch of IoT devices which advertise their services with mDNS.
For this, I use NsdManager.DiscoveryListener() together with NsdManager.discoverServices().
All good when it comes to discovery: onServiceFound() is triggered and the service is resolved by NsdManager.resolveService().
The issue is with onServiceLost() which is never triggered. I would expect when the IoT device loses its wifi connection this function to be triggered.
I start discoverServices() and stop it only when the Android app exits.
Any clue why onServiceLost is not triggered?
Here is my code
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
...
public bollean serviceFound = false;
...
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    ...
    nsdManager =  (NsdManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NSD_SERVICE);
    wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    checkpermisions();
    lookForService(this);
        {
        ...
        }
    ...
    }
public void conn_event(String constat, int color)
    {
    userMessage.setText(constat);
    userMessage.setTextColor(color);
    }

}


public class WiFiUtils
{
...
static void lookForService(MainActivity mAct)
    {
    if(mAct.wifiManager.isWifiEnabled() == false)
        {
        mAct.conn_event("WiFI activation", mAct.getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
        if(mAct.wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true) == false)
            {
            mAct.conn_event("Cannot activate WiFi", mAct.getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
            return;
            }
        }
    if(mAct.wifiInfo.getNetworkId() == -1)
        {
        mAct.conn_event("Not connected to any WiFi networks", mAct.getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
        return;
        }
    int localIP = mAct.wifiInfo.getIpAddress();
    mAct.t.localIP = localIP;
    resolveListener = new NsdManager.ResolveListener()
        {
        @Override
        public void onResolveFailed(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo, int errorCode)
            {
            // Called when the resolve fails. Use the error code to debug.
            Log.e(TAG, "Resolve failed: " + errorCode);
            }

        @Override
        public void onServiceResolved(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo)
            {
            Log.i(TAG, "Resolve Succeeded. " + serviceInfo);
            mAct.conn_event("Service resolved", mAct.getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
            }
        };
    discoveryListener = new NsdManager.DiscoveryListener()
        {
        // Called as soon as service discovery begins.
        @Override
        public void onDiscoveryStarted(String regType)
            {
            Log.d(TAG, "Service discovery started");
            }

        @Override
        public void onServiceFound(NsdServiceInfo service)
            {
            // A service was found! Do something with it.
            Log.i(TAG, "Service discovery success" + service);
            Log.i(TAG, "host: " + service.getHost());
            mAct.conn_event("Service found", mAct.getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
            mAct.nsdManager.resolveService(service, resolveListener);
            }

        @Override
        public void onServiceLost(NsdServiceInfo service)
            {
            // When the network service is no longer available.
            // Internal bookkeeping code goes here.
            Log.e(TAG, "service lost: " + service);
            mAct.conn_event("Service lost", mAct.getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
            }

        @Override
        public void onDiscoveryStopped(String serviceType)
            {
            Log.i(TAG, "Discovery stopped: " + serviceType);
            }

        @Override
        public void onStartDiscoveryFailed(String serviceType, int errorCode)
            {
            Log.e(TAG, "Discovery failed: Error code:" + errorCode);
            //nsdManager.stopServiceDiscovery(this);
            }

        @Override
        public void onStopDiscoveryFailed(String serviceType, int errorCode)
            {
            Log.e(TAG, "Discovery failed: Error code:" + errorCode);
            //nsdManager.stopServiceDiscovery(this);
            }

        };
    mAct.nsdManager.discoverServices("_http._tcp", NsdManager.PROTOCOL_DNS_SD, discoveryListener);
    }
...
}

